# Play! Framework - Evolution don't start automatically on Server with MySQL

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.3, playframework-evolutions

After starting my application on the server it connects with my MySQL database.

```
2015-04-19 17:00:38,636 - [INFO] - from play in main 
database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/crowdfundme
```

But then it crashes everytime the database is involved.

```
Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Table  'crowdfundme.user' doesn't exist 
Bind values:[] 
Query was:
select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.age c2, t0.money c3, t0.nationality c4, t0.has_funded c5, t0.has_answered_questions c6, t0.chosen_bike c7,   t0.funding_amount c8, t0.money_before_funding c9 from user t0
```

The evolution script is not applied, but it can't be applied because there is no possibility to do it, when I load the page for the first time.

I tried with the normal tricks to apply the evolution script automatically:

```
evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

But now I can't think any further. Maybe there is something totally simple I can't see by myself? Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out by myself. You have to let play generate the evolution scheme. Use in your application.conf `db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL"` to create the evolution with the MySQL dialect. 
In my case I had to delete the "sequences" in the 1.sql so that is worked with my MySQL database on my server, but maybe you can find a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first evolution? Maybe is there some down evolution?

Comment: I don't have any 1.sql,... because I thought that Ebean can handle them for me (as in development mode with JDBC). Any down evolution is applied with `applyDownEvolutions.default=true` isn't it?

Comment: The evolution plugin generate the 1.sql in development mode file, the production mode use the same file created by develoment mode.

Comment: I deleted the 1.sql file before deploying it on my server so it don't cause any problems. Or do you mean to test it with a local MySQL database and then use the same 1.sql if it is created?

Comment: If you have deleted the 1.sql file evolutions doesn't work. Redeploy with sql file or handle the table creation manually.

Comment: Yeah I figured out today... anyway thank you for the answer! :)